# Cypress intercept threw cross origin error with supplied statusCode

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress 6.3.0. Why does the following happen?

```
cy.intercept('https://some.random.url', {
  statusCode: 200
})
```

threw a `Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load` error

but

```
cy.intercept('http://some.random.url')
```

did not.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71277156/17865804) as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages.html#Cypress-detected-a-cross-origin-error-happened-on-page-load) setting `chromeWebSecurity` to `false` in your configuration file (cypress.json by default) will solve this issue.

```
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

Comment: thanks, i know this. my question isn't about solving this issue. my question is why this is happening only when i supply `{ statusCode: 200 }`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different protocols there in the code snippets you quote: `https` vs `http`. This is possibly tripping Cypress up.